# Is there an anderson-darling goodness of fit test for two datasets?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I know ad.test() can be used for testing normality.

Is it possible to get ad.test to compare the distributions from two data samples?

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rgev(2000)
ad.test(x,y)
```

How can I perform the Anderson-Darling test on 2 samples?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the A-D test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test) mentions this under the heading "Non-parametric k-sample tests."  Its reference, a 1987 JASA paper by Sholz and Stephens, is freely available at http://www.cithep.caltech.edu/~fcp/statistics/hypothesisTest/PoissonConsistency/ScholzStephens1987.pdf .

Comment: If the question is: how can I do it in R (as the tag suggests): good question (+1) (and the answer is probably: rig it yourself), albeit somewhat misplaced here ([StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is a better place for this kind of question).

Comment: @Nick Finding or implementing a GoF test, whether in R or any other language, fits squarely within our interest in all things statistical.

Comment: @whuber: I stand corrected: I just read the relevant part of the faq. Still, it's a thin line between love and hate. But I didn't vote to migrate :-)

Comment: @Nick I agree about the thin line.  When a question focuses purely on the mechanics of programming, its appropriateness here becomes doubtful.  You can find [periodic discussions about this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/584) on meta.

Answer (score 9):

Package `adk` was replaced by package `kSamples`:

Try:

```
install.packages("kSamples")  
library(kSamples)
ad.test(runif(50), rnorm(30))
```

Comment: the `kSamples::ad.test` function is rather slow. Is there a more efficient alternative?

Answer (score 5):

The adk package for R does this. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adk/

```
install.packages("adk")
library(adk)
adk.test(runif(50), rnorm(30))
```

Comment: The adk package was removed from CRAN. Is there an alternative ?