# How to test if many samples are from the same distribution?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, goodness-of-fit

For each day of the week, I observe $n_i$ independently chosen values from some process. I would like to be able to answer the following two questions.

Are the distributions from which the samples are drawn the same for each day?

If not, can we split the days into two groups of days so the distributions are the same in each group?

If I only had two days then it seems you could do a two sample Anderson-Darling test.

Can my two questions be answered?

Comment: You can check the answers and the comments for the question below for an Andersen Darling test for more than one sample. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/is-there-an-anderson-darling-goodness-of-fit-test-for-two-datasets

Comment: [k-sample Anderson-Darling type tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#Non-parametric_k-sample_tests) exist. However, you may want to consider the possibility of serial correlation over time.

Comment: Can you say more about what you want to check for?  Are you wondering if the mean differs by day, the SD, the skew, etc?  Are you wondering if the data come from different types of distributions (eg, normal vs uniform)?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to

1. Fit each day's n values to a non-parametric kernel density estimation
2. At the end of the week you will have 7 estimated PDFs
3. Show these PDFs on a single plot
4. Any PDF that overlays another may indicate that their data came from the same distribution

Comment: "Overlay" of PDFs is vague, non-quantitative, and generally does not work as a useful statistic for testing equality of distributions.  Moreover, the result might be (and will be) sensitive to the choice of kernel radius.